# Setting a form field's default value from a request variable

Tags: python, django, django-forms

In Django, is it possible to set the default value of a form field to be tied to a request variable. e.g. `request.META['REMOTE_ADDR']`.

This is just an example, it'd like to be use any of the headers available in the `request` variable without passing it explicitly to the form.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible, since the request object is not globally available, and thus it is not available in the form unless explicitly passed in. The `initial` argument exists for exactly the problem you are trying to solve. You should probably use

```
form = YourForm(..., initial={'your_field': request.META['REMOTE_ADDR'])
```

in your view.

Edit:

If you like to pass in the `request` explicitly, you can use something like this, and then just pass `request=request` when you instantiates the form:

```
class YourForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.request = kwargs.pop('request')
        super(YourForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    # ... use self.request in clean etc
```